# Do the students have a right to know the name and quealifications of the person that marks their work?

Tags: coursework, grading

A student hands in his coursework. When he gets it back, the comments on the paper are incorrectly stating that the student exceeded the word count (they didn't). They are also incorrect on specific items.

The student points out these errors and asks

1. who marked the paper and
2. whether the mark could be improved, given the wordcount wasn't exceeded.

The university refuses to give the name of the marker and to improve the mark even by a single point.

Can they get away with that? If they are not giving the name of the marker, then there must be something wrong. Are there any justifications ?

Comment: So what is your question? (I can't see one in the body of your post, and the answer to the question in the title is obviously "It depends (on the country, the university, ...)")

Comment: Unfortunately this is likely going to depend on your university regulations. There is almost certainly a formal appeal process that can be followed.

Comment: Who did you contact? Since you refer to "the university" I assume you contacted some administrative unit within the university. In all universities I know, they would be the wrong persons to contact; they cannot do anything in situations like these. So that is good news: you are not in conflict with the university (yet), you just asked the wrong person. The person to contact is the person teaching this course (or coordinating this course, if there are multiple people teaching that course). This is the person to speak to, not the person who graded your work.

Comment: Sometimes I let TAs grade work. However, in that case I am still responsible. For starters, the TAs are still learning to teach. So, if some mistake happend, you would have to talk to me, and not the TA. Moreover, I would not tell you which TA graded your work. I would talk to the TA myself. So that would be a case where you would not know who graded your work.

Comment: Is not the right thing to do is let them mark the paper and you moderate it?

Comment: What do you hope to achieve by finding out who did the grading? What would be your next step, once you had that information?

Comment: I decide the grades. If the TAs grade, then they do the work, but I, and only I, make the final decision. So you only talk to me, because I am the only one who can change your grade. My talk with the TA if (s)he made a mistake, is only there to be a learning experience for her or him. Learning experiences of other people are none of your business.

Answer (score 4):

No, you don't have the right to the name of the marker if they are another student. The professor is ultimately responsible for the actions of TAs, so the first appeal is properly to them.

You have a moral right to a fair judgement of your work, but that is really all. If you don't get that, then you have a right to complain and seek redress, but what happens depends on university rules and such.

You can make an assumption, of course about the qualifications of graders, but only in general. They are people who are trusted by the professor and have enough knowledge to settle most (but not all) issues. But privacy rules/regulations/laws don't require, or possibly even permit, the names to be released. This is to prevent harassment, especially of people who are caught in the middle and have little power to affect things.

Comment: Hi Buffy - There is no professor and nobody is taking responsibility - International students are paying 15 K - is it right their papers are marked by TA and if they were that is not a problem if someone puts their name to the paper - Uni's are public bodies and therefore have a duty of care

Comment: Why is there no professor? That isn't making sense to me.  Someone must have overall responsibility.

Comment: It does not matter who marked. There is one person or entity who is responsible for the integrity of the mark, and that's where you appeal and, if unsuccessful, OP has to escalate the appeal process.

Comment: No all modules have a professor - if you mean the head of the school - yes there is. However, the point I am trying to find out is - what justifications are there to withold the name of the marker. And it is not just the mark Uni's are public bodies they should be open and accountable by hiding the name of markers I think they are in breach of that duty

Comment: @HCochrane which country are you in? What I think is causing some confusion here is that in the academic world most of us are familiar with, any class has a professor (or lecturer) who is in charge. There is no such thing as a class with no instructor who is accountable for grading decisions and whose name students will know, but maybe in your country there is. This is important for the purposes of offering you useful advice, so maybe you can clarify?